# Counting all the characters in the file using Spark/scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I calculate all the characters in the file using Spark/Scala? Here is what I am doing in the spark shell :

```
scala> val logFile = sc.textFile("ClasspathLength.txt")
scala> val counts = logFile.flatMap(line=>line.split("").map(char=>(char,1))).reduceByKey(_ + _)
scala> println(counts.count())
scala> 62
```

I am getting incorrect count here. Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - are you trying to get (1) the total number of characters in the file; or (2) the number of _distinct_ characters; or (3) the number of times each distinct character appears in the file?

Comment: I just need total characters in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is:

1. Counting the number of times each unique character appears in the input:

   ```
   val counts = logFile.flatMap(line=>line.split("").map(char=>(char,1))).reduceByKey(_ + _)
   ```

   and then:
2. Counting the number of *records* in this result (using `counts.count()`), which ignores the actual *values* you calculated in the previous step

If you're interested in displaying the total number characters in the file - there's no need for grouping at all - you can map each line to its *length* and then use the implicit conversion into `DoubleRDDFunctions` to call `sum()`:

```
logFile.map(_.length).sum()
```

Alternatively you can `flatMap` into separate record per character and then use `count`:

```
logFile.flatMap(_.toList).count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val spark=SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[4]")
      .appName("Nos of Word Count")
      .getOrCreate()

    val sparkConfig=spark.sparkContext
    sparkConfig.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val rdd1=sparkConfig.textFile("data/mini.txt")
    println(rdd1.count())

    val rdd2=rdd1.flatMap(f=>{f.split(" ")})//.map(x=>x.toInt)
    println(rdd2.count())

    val rdd3=rdd2
      .map(w=>(w.count(p=>true))).map(w=>w.toInt)

    println(rdd3.sum().round)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

All you need here is flatMap + count

```
logFile.flatMap(identity).count
```

Comment: what is 'identity' here?

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question. user8061428 will you please edit your answer and be more specific?